Python: hidden imports. Where does this thing get imported?
In Python, what are the possible ways to have something imported without having
import ... or from ... import ... in the file?
The question was born after working with something close to the following code:
my_logs.py
from logging import DEBUG, INFO, WARNING, ERROR, CRITICAL
from logging import Handler, Logger, makeLogRecord, _nameToLevel, _lock

...  # Lots of company code here.

logging = logger  # some form of custom logging class

decorator.py
# The usual way we import our custom logging:
from my_project.my_logs import logging

...  # Lots of company code here.

def provide_session_decorator():
   # decorator code

code.py
# No import to my_logs! Neither on top of the file, nor in the code below.
# No import to logging!
from my_project.decorator import provide_session_decorator

...  # Lots of company code here

@provide_session_decorator
def some_function(session=None):
  logging.debug("Bla bla")  # Does not log anything. Probably wrong logging imported?
  logging.error("Bla bla")  # Does log something.

Somehow, some form of logging is found by python's interpreter here, but no logging is explicitly imported. In Pycharm, when I try to add import to my_logs, it is grayed out and treated as unused. Any idea how this happened?

Looks like the log level is to high to log debug lines. Also you should avoid using module name as variable but this is clearly not the problem here.

When custom logger is used the way it should be, all levels are logged correctly. Only in this situation it seems that wrong logging somehow got imported.

As a general rule of thumb: if a name isn't explicitly being defined in a module, it can't exist. So, are you sure you're not just overlooking where the logging name gets defined? Perhaps it's a dynamic import in a function and setting the name via setattr or globals? That'd be terrible practice (because confusing, Q.E.D.), but possible. As a super terrible variation on that: other modules may be injecting the name via sys.modules?!

print(logging) may be helpful

The only way for something unexpected to end up imported into the namespace is with from <module> import * otherwise only what is explicitly specified is included. Either you are not running the file you think you are or the code you've omitted is setting up logging in the file global namespace. The other possibility is provide_session_decorator is messing with the function's __globals__ to include logging.
